# Is it really good by using react-helmet npm package for seo?-Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, seo, react-helmet

I'm a newbie to the `react js`. Please avoid this question if you think this was stupid, and I'am really thinking from 1 week that is `react-helmet` really very very good for `react application to implement seo`? Please kindly give me answer. because some will say no, `react-helmet` is not good and some will say yes, its really good.

Please give me correct answer because iam suffering from 1 week. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry Raghunadh. This is the very definition of an opinion-based question, and is off-topic for SO.

Comment: @Andy bro please give me answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React helmet provides a Helmet component that helps you change the document head. Some tags in the head: title, meta. But I think you want good SEO, you should choose the server-side side to render instead of using this component. It only helps you change the content of some tags. Additionally, you also use javascript to do the same purporse directly.

Answer (score 0):

React helmet is most useful for social media preview optimization.  It can provide the meta data with the information that social networks show when somebody shares a link to your site.

For search engines, you need more than just the head meta data.  Search engines need to see the full page.  For SEO you should use server side rendering (SSR), pre-rendering, or check that search engine bots can view your full content by rendering JavaScript.

For more information see this question which I answered on Webmasters: [Is server side rendering a must have for good SEO for a React website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/130430/is-server-side-rendering-a-must-have-for-good-seo-for-a-react-website)